# How to make plastic shine after removing the stickers on it using cooking oil?

Tags: plastic

After removing the stickers on some of the plastic materials using cooking oil, the plastic lose its shininess. How to I get that shininess back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all these crappy aerosols that say shine this, shine that..

Finding the right one is very difficult. I used to buy this creamy liquid from a chemical supplier.. It was amazing! It restored the plastic to its natural, factory looking shine. This was in South Africa and years ago..

So i found [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/MUC-OFF-BIKE-MOTORCYCLE-SILICONE-SHINE-PROTECTIVE-GLOSS-/190608497439?pt=UK_Motorcycle_Parts&hash=item2c6126db1f).. (it is not my shop.. its just the only guy who has this stuff)

[image]

I found this after testing and trying ... 12 other sprays, miracle shines and what not. This is not exactly what i used in SA.. but it works well

- You generously spray the area with the shine(usually you will do the whole item or the whole side for even looking shine).. leave it for 5-15 minutes.
- using a kitchen towel (not toilet tissue) you will polish the area vigorously while removing excess
- Leave it for some more time.. up to hours. Use a microfibre cloth to finish off the polish.
- I have made many old, junk from the bin look like new again.. and nobody new the difference.
- Use some elbow grease..

The key is to find a silicone based solution. Good Luck